# static_cast to a different type, and move the result

Tags: c++, move-semantics, static-cast

Say I want to static_cast an object of type `S` to type `T` and move assign the result:

```
template <typename S, typename T>
void f(T& t, S s);
```

I can think of four ways to write it:

```
template <typename S, typename T>
void f(T& t, S s) {
    t = static_cast<T>(s);
    t = static_cast<T>(std::move(s));
    t = static_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>&&>(s);
    t = static_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>&&>(std::move(s));
}
```

Do some or all of these four lines do the same thing? What's the preferred way to do it?

Comment: The preferred way is to not do it.  What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: All of these move-assign the result; the question is whether or not you want to move out of `s` into the temporary  (and if so, the second one is the way to go)

Comment: BTW `t = T(std::move(s));` is simpler syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do some or all of these four lines do the same thing?

All of them move-assign `t`. The conversions in third and fourth are superfluous. First one copies the argument into the temporary, and the second moves. The second is superior. Although another matter is, whether the function is needed in the first place.

Comment: I think the third one is copy constructing the temporary too, as it doesn't compile if I make S noncopyable. So as I see it now 1=3, 2=4. And yes, the function is not needed, it's only illustrative. I would write the code inline.

Comment: @Arcinde you may be right. It should use `static_cast` for the rvalue conversion to be equivalent to `std::move` by definition. Regardless, those are superfluous.